# Replace special characters in a file with their unicode code (Python)

Tags: python, file, unicode, replace, special-characters

I have an interesting question. Suppose to have a list of chars with their matching representation in unicode:

```
list_of_special_chars = [
    ('Ą', b'\u0104'),
    ('ą', b'\u0105'),
    ('Ę', b'\u0118'),
    ('ę', b'\u0119'),
    ('Ó', b'\xd3'),
    ('ó', b'\xf3'),
    ('Ć', b'\u0106'),
    ('ć', b'\u0107'),
    ('Ł', b'\u0141'),
    ('ł', b'\u0142'),
    ('Ń', b'\u0143'),
    ('ń', b'\u0144'),
    ('Ś', b'\u015a'),
    ('ś', b'\u015b'),
    ('Ź', b'\u0179'),
    ('ź', b'\u017a'),
    ('Ż', b'\u017b'),
    ('ż', b'\u017c')
]
```

Now, consider to have a text file with this phrase: **Cześć, jak się masz?**

How can I replace the text into the file in way to create a new file that looks like this: **Cze\u015b\u0107, jak si\u0119 masz?**

I tried different ways but I can't solve this type of problem for the way in which python handles strings. For example `"Czesć".replace("ć", "\u0107")` is always the same word.

Comment: Why do you want to? You're replacing whatever standard encoding the file already uses with your own proprietary encoding.

Comment: I had to edit some JavaScript files and I used python to process them.

Comment: What is your Python version? What do you mean by *"edit some JavaScript files"*? The text doesn't look like javascript source code. Have your considered `json`? It looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096)

Comment: Thanks for the response but escaping is exactly what I was looking for. It's a complex scenario and I can't give you more information about it. The code is a part of the python script that I used to open and process the JavaScript files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash so that `\u` isn't treated as the beginning of a Python escape sequence.

```
"Czesć".replace("ć", "\\u0107")
```